# How to check if an application is it's first run or not in xamarin crosspaltform

Tags: xaml, xamarin, c#-3.0

I want to show some pages in the first time app is installed, and the next time when I open the app show some other pages.

I tried this code

```
 protected override void OnStart()
    {
        if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("id"))
        {
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page2());
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Current.Properties["id"] = 2;

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page1());
        }          
    }
```

The values in the Properties dictionary are only stored when the app goes to sleep

Comment: Ok so you want something. But what did you already tried. What is your current output and what is your problem ?

Comment: Is there any solution to store the values to the Properties dictionary when the app is  closed. Please help me..

Answer (score 2):

For a cross-platform approach, you can use the [Settings Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin)

Then you can create a boolean property, for example, `DidOpenOnce`, and if it is false, show your initial welcome page or whatever. Then afterwards, set it to true.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void checkApplicationInstallState()
    {
        //retreive
        var prefs = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("MyApp", FileCreationMode.Private);
        var somePref = prefs.GetBool("IsApplicationOpenedForOnce", null);
        if (!somePref) {
            // Your Application is opened for the very first time. Now change the value to true as you have now opened the app so next time opening this application should get a true value.
            var prefEditor = prefs.Edit();
            prefEditor.PutBool(true, "IsApplicationOpenedForOnce");
            prefEditor.Commit();
        }

}
```

Comment: Write the code in a function which runs as soon as an Application is opened.

Comment: The problem with such local approaches is that if user deletes App's data (from device Settings), these approaches won't work.

Comment: The more reliable way would be saving and retrieving this bool property in/from server.

Answer (score 0):

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("FirstUse"))
            {
                //Do things when it's NOT the first use...
                loadinit();
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Current.Properties["FirstUse"] = false;
                //Do things when it IS the first use...

            }


        }
        public async void loadinit()
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoadPage());
        }
```